# SQL - Only Return Row If Column Does Not Have Same Value

Tags: sql

I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to return rows that has only 1 value match in a column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(50),
    PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(50)
    STAMP DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1, 'Tom', 'Lew', 'tom@hotmail.com', '11111111111', '2019-08-23 15:12:06.807')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (2, 'Tom', 'Lew', 'tom@hotmail.com', '22222222222', '2019-08-27 15:12:06.807')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (3, 'Jack', 'Stan', 'jstan@hotmail.com', '3333333333', '2019-08-03 15:12:06.807')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (4, 'John', 'Doe', 'jdoe@hotmail.com',  '44444444444', '2019-08-13 15:12:06.807')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (5, 'Peter', 'Griffin', 'pgriffin@hotmail.com', '55555555555', '2019-07-23 15:12:06.807')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (6, 'Homer', 'Simpson', 'hsimpson@hotmail.com', '66666666666', 2019-08-23 15:12:06.807')

SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
FROM TEST GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
HAVING COUNT (FirstName) <= 1
```

So the result is supposed return everything except for 'Tom' because 'Tom' has more than 1 value matches in the First Name column. However, it's returning everything.

If I do a SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email and GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Email, it comes back correctly.

Comment: What's the database (and version)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `not exists`.  If you only care about the first name:

```
select t.*
from test t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.firstname = t.firstname and
                        t2.id <> t.id
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your select query is two toms' don't have the same **phonenumber**. If you are going to include the **phonenumber** in the `GROUP BY` clause it will give you 2 unique rows for both the toms. You need to decide your unique composite columns for `GROUP BY`.

If you are only concerned about **FirstName** your query will be like this.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
FROM TEST GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT (FirstName) <= 1
```

If you are taking **LastName** and **Email** into `GROUP BY`, then:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
FROM TEST GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Email
HAVING COUNT (FirstName) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you check for unique `FirstName`s you should only `GROUP BY FirstName` and aggregate on the other columns with `MAX()` or `MIN()` (it does not make any difference because the condition in the `HAVING` clause makes sure that only 1 value of these columns exists):

```
SELECT FirstName, 
  MAX(LastName) LastName, MAX(Email) Email, MAX(PhoneNumber) PhoneNumber
FROM TEST 
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g98UCupVKbAWbz3dxLGaye/0).
Results:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Email                | PhoneNumber |
| --------- | -------- | -------------------- | ----------- |
| Homer     | Simpson  | hsimpson@hotmail.com | 66666666666 |
| Jack      | Stan     | jstan@hotmail.com    | 3333333333  |
| John      | Doe      | jdoe@hotmail.com     | 44444444444 |
| Peter     | Griffin  | pgriffin@hotmail.com | 55555555555 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I will exclude the duplicate record using ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT * FROM(
              SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY firstname ORDER BY firstname) AS rn
              FROM test
            )
 WHERE rn=1;
```

Hope this helps.